# Getting incorrect output while calling python keyword in robot test

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I am running below code, which runs fine in python , but in robot test its not working:

Python Code :

```
def test_gender(Gender=None):
    if Gender is "m":
        Gender="Male"
    elif Gender is "f":
        Gender="Female"
    print Gender
    return Gender

test_gender("m")
```

Expected Output: Male ,

Python Output : Male

Robot Test :

```
*** Settings ***
Library    test_var.py

*** Test Cases ***
Test_Gender
test_gender     m
```

Expected Output : Male ,

Robot output : m

Issue : Robot test is printing incorrect output "m" instead of "Male" .
What is the way to get correct output from robot test for this scenario.

Comment: You're testing identity with `is`, not equality.

Comment: Replaced "is" with  equality "==".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per above comment replaced "is" with equality "==".
Robot test is giving correct output now.

Comment: You can self-accept the answer - it really is that, and solves it for you :)